# How to let a user in "internal Facebook App browser" to like my page without directing to a new page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I visit [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) (Facebook Like Button official page) in my Facebook browser, the like button is working very gracefully.

It works this way:

[1 - Click the "like"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPETQ.png)

[2 - There will be a sparkle animation showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fobxi.png)

[3 - Then the like action is done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNClG.png)

However, when I put the same code in a [page](https://www.arealme.com/which-german-city-should-i-live-in/en/) of mine, still in Facebook internal browser, after clicking the like button, there's no animation and I am redirected to a new page, in which I'm asked to confirm the like action.

[Here is the screenshot of the new confirm box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb7Na.png)

Is there a way to let the user like my page directly without this "Do you want to like this page" confirm box? I want this feature because people are taking actions on my page and if they are directed to another page, the status of that page is gone.

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Comment: The confirmation page will disappear when Facebook have enough confidence in your page.

Comment: Is there any official documents on that? Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: so this is a pure guess? or did you see any other people talking about this?

Comment: I've seen it before.

Comment: [Social Plugins FAQ: Why are people seeing a "Confirm" button when they click on my Like button?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_251162528583504)